# c++ beginning to background

Tags: c++, windows, background, hide

I make the bakcground running program.
this program is just simple [05:00 - reboot]..

I want hide the console windows..

Start from the beginning to background the console window

help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "shellapi.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        time_t timer = time(NULL);
        struct tm t;
        localtime_s(&t, &timer);
        int count_1 = 0;

        if (t.tm_hour == 5) {
            if (t.tm_min == 00) {
                if (count_1 == 0) {
                    count_1 = 1;
                    WCHAR path[260];
                    GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, 260);
                    HWND console = FindWindow(L"ConsoleWindowClass", path);
                    if (IsWindow(console))
                        ShowWindow(console, SW_HIDE); // hides the window
                    system("shutdown -r");
                    if (IsWindow(console))
                        ShowWindow(console, SW_SHOW); // shows the window
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Axalo The simplest way to hide console window is compiling program as `window application` instead of `console application`. This is done by the compiler parameter.

Comment: @Gim GiYneon Why you try to hide console widow just before restarting.

Comment: @Gim GiYneon `while (true)` is very inefficient. Put [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the code.

Comment: @Gim GiYneon What does the variable `count_1`?

Comment: As you are clearly writing a windows program (and using the dreaded `system` call anyway), try:  `int main()  
{  
    system("shutdown /t 300 /r");  
    return 0;  
}`

Comment: @frasnian The program aims to restart the system at 5:00 am.

Comment: Then just get the current system time, figure out the difference in seconds between "now" and "0500" and set the `/t` parameter to that - see `difftime()`.

Comment: @frasnian This can cause problems if the system is hibernating in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would use the `WinMain` entry point instead of `main`.
But you need to tell your compiler that you're using `WinMain` which is compiler dependent.

By the way, there is a simpler way to hide the console window.

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

But be aware that using this method the console is still being created and you might see it for a fraction of a second.

Comment: It is not needed, so there is no point to remember about it. It is not related to the problem.

Comment: @NO_NAME There is no console being created when using `WinMain`. That's perfect if you want your program to be run in the background.

Comment: This is not dependent on the `WinMain` but the compiler settings. Perhaps your compiler turns them according to the function used.